# Jquery FullCalendar: JSON error unless hardcoded

Tags: jquery, json, internet-explorer, fullcalendar

I am trying to set up the JSON Feed for the Adam Shaw jquery full calendar, and can get it to work in Chrome, but FireFox/IE. In the later the browsers refuse to render the appointments passed as a JSON string unless they are hardcoded.

I have put a day into this and after trying many JSON derivations I found a code example that works, but could not dynamically replicate it with my data.  Finally I figured out that the difference was that code snippet cut and pasted was hard coded.

Fullcalendar seems pretty accomodating of many different types of JSON (array/object) but for some reason IE knows if the PHP string is hard coded or just echoed from a variable. Does something get sent that lets it know what is happening at the server end?

My PHP looks like this (foreach is set to work with Zend db-rowset):

```
foreach($rowset as $row){
            $apptArray = array();
            $apptArray['title'] = $row -> title; 
            $apptArray['allDay'] = ''; 
            $apptArray['id'] = $row -> appt_id; 
            $apptArray['participants'] = $row -> participants; 
            $apptArray['organizer'] = $row -> organizer; 
            $apptArray['propId'] = $row -> prop_id; 
            $apptArray['reason'] = $row -> reason; 
            $apptArray['start'] = date('Y-m-d  H:i:s', $row -> start); 
            $apptArray['end'] = date('Y-m-d  H:i:s', $row -> end); 
            array_push($jsonArray,$apptArray);

            }
            echo json_encode($jsonArray);
```

if I just load the JSON feed url in the browser this returns a JSON string that looks like this:

```
[
{
    "title":"Lunch",
    "allDay":"",
    "id":"9",
    "participants":"456",
    "organizer":"36",
    "propId":"14",
    "reason":"to meet",
    "start":"2012-10-12 11:00:00",
    "end":"2012-10-12 11:30:00"
 },
 {
    "title":"dd",
    "allDay":"",
    "id":"15",
    "participants":"45",
    "organizer":"36",
    "propId":"45",
    "reason":"meet again",
    "start":"2012-10-12 09:00:00",
    "end":"2012-10-12 09:30:00"
 }
```

]

This is where things get strange.  If fullCalendar calls this from my script it will not render any appointments. But if I take the same string above, hardcode it, and just echo the JSON string direct. The string renders just fine. (see below)

```
echo '[{"title":"Lunch","allDay":"","id":"9","participants":"456","organizer":"36","propId":"14","reason":"to eet","start":"2012-10-12 11:00:00","end":"2012-10-12 11:30:00"},{"title":"dd","allDay":"","id":"15","participants":"45","organizer":"36","propId":"45","reason":"asdf","start":"2012-10-12 11:00:00","end":"2012-10-12 11:30:00"}]';
```

Could this be that when the JSON display in the browser from my script has been changed in some way? Has anyone come across this elsewhere?

The final bit of relevant code is the fullcalendar set up option:

```
eventSources:[
                  {
        url: 'http://local/tenant/calendar/apptsfeed',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response) {
             alert('this has worked');

        },
        error: function(response) {
            alert('error');

        },
        color: 'yellow',   // a non-ajax option
        textColor: 'black' // a non-ajax option
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this took me a long time to figure out.

However, thought I would pass on what worked for me in case there are any other IE users out there.

The issue seems to be a date format issue.  Basically IE is more sensitive than chrome for some reason.

I found a reference to the correct format on this link
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/

*'you may specify a string in IETF format (ex: "Wed, 18 Oct 2009 13:00:00 EST"), a string in ISO8601 format (ex: "2009-11-05T13:15:30Z") or a UNIX timestamp.'*

For what ever reason if I use IS8601 it works just fine in IE9.  This basically involved inserting a 'T' after the date.

Hope someone finds this useful.

Answer (score 0):

try putting datatype as `dataType: 'json'` in your event sources and see.

```
eventSources:[
              {
    url: 'http://local/tenant/calendar/apptsfeed',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
         alert('this has worked');

    },
    error: function(response) {
        alert('error');

    },
    color: 'yellow',   // a non-ajax option
    textColor: 'black' // a non-ajax option
}
```